# Computing fibonacci in c++ function and throwing compile-time error

Tags: c++, c++17, fibonacci, static-assert

I need to write this function fibo.
If the number is too big it should be shown as compile error (the last line of main function)
The main function should stay like it is.
Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>

int fibo(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    //if (n>=300) throws ... ?
    return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2);
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(fibo(7) == 34);
    const int k = fibo(9);
    std::cout << k << std::endl;
    const int l = fibo(300); // 300th Fibonacci number is large for int
}
```

Comment: By the way, 300 is much too big. fibo will overflow an int for much smaller values.

Comment: @cigien what should I do?  to find that value and put it in if statement instead of 300?
but in main it should stay as it is... could I ask you to tell me how static_assert works?

Comment: Yes, just look up that value. IIRC it's 48, or maybe that's for `long`. The call in `main` will still fail to compile. `static_assert` just checks if the expression is true at compile time.

Comment: @cigien so since the expression ( static_assert(fibo(7) == 34); ) is not true nothing happens?

Comment: No, it forces a compiler error. Note that I changed it in the demo in my answer.

Comment: oh, yes, I see it now. So when I comment it and run I get "terminate called without an active exception Aborted (core dumped)".Was that error supposed to be since we passed argument 300?

Comment: Yes, it's a run time exception if `fibo` is called at run time with 300.

Comment: I changed const int to constexpr because I need it to be a compiler error. So this means the problem is solved? I put in if statement 47 because over it is not int range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `fibo` a `constexpr` function, and then `throw` if the argument is invalid. The `throw` in a `constexpr` function will lead to a compile time error if `fibo` is evaluated at compile time, and a run time error otherwise:

```
constexpr int fibo(int n)
{
    if (n >= 300) throw;
    if (n <= 1) return n; 
    return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2); 
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
int j = fibo(300);             // run time error
constexpr int k = fibo(300);   // compile time error
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YWhsPc).

Note that you can't `static_assert` inside the definition of `fibo` since the condition depends on the function argument, which is not a constant expression.